# screen_capturer_mac.mm:462:11: error: 'CGDisplayStreamUpdateGetRects' is only available on macOS 13.0 or newer [-Werror,-Wunguarded-availability-new]

Tags: c++, macos, chromium

I am compile the chrome in macOS 13.2.1 with M1 pro chip, when I run this command, show error:

```
➜  src git:(64ca7395b4) autoninja -C out/Default chrome
ninja: Entering directory `out/Default'
[20433/54517] OBJCXX obj/third_party/webrtc/modules/desktop_capture/desktop_capture_objc/screen_capturer_mac.o
FAILED: obj/third_party/webrtc/modules/desktop_capture/desktop_capture_objc/screen_capturer_mac.o
../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/clang++ -MMD -MF obj/third_party/webrtc/modules/desktop_capture/desktop_capture_objc/screen_capturer_mac.o.d -DDCHECK_ALWAYS_ON=1 -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -DCR_XCODE_VERSION=1430 -DCR_CLANG_REVISION=\"llvmorg-17-init-4759-g547e3456-2\" -DCOMPONENT_BUILD -DCR_LIBCXX_REVISION=049d48aa99786a2452537a5f5e3c411c741abb82 -D_LIBCPP_ENABLE_ASSERTIONS=1 -D_DEBUG -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DWEBRTC_ENABLE_PROTOBUF=1 -DWEBRTC_STRICT_FIELD_TRIALS=0 -DRTC_ENABLE_VP9 -DRTC_DAV1D_IN_INTERNAL_DECODER_FACTORY -DWEBRTC_HAVE_SCTP -DENABLE_EXTERNAL_AUTH -DHAVE_WEBRTC_VIDEO -DLOGGING_INSIDE_WEBRTC -DWEBRTC_ARCH_ARM64 -DWEBRTC_HAS_NEON -DWEBRTC_LIBRARY_IMPL -DWEBRTC_ENABLE_SYMBOL_EXPORT -DWEBRTC_ENABLE_AVX2 -DWEBRTC_NON_STATIC_TRACE_EVENT_HANDLERS=0 -DWEBRTC_CHROMIUM_BUILD -DWEBRTC_POSIX -DWEBRTC_MAC -DABSL_ALLOCATOR_NOTHROW=1 -I../.. -Igen -I../../buildtools/third_party/libc++ -I../../third_party/webrtc_overrides -I../../third_party/webrtc -Igen/third_party/webrtc -I../../third_party/abseil-cpp -I../../third_party/perfetto/include -Igen/third_party/perfetto/build_config -Igen/third_party/perfetto -I../../third_party/libyuv/include -I../../third_party/webrtc/sdk/objc -I../../third_party/webrtc/sdk/objc/base  -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wimplicit-fallthrough -Wextra-semi -Wunreachable-code-aggressive -Wthread-safety -Wunguarded-availability -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-psabi -Wloop-analysis -Wno-unneeded-internal-declaration -Wenum-compare-conditional -Wno-ignored-pragma-optimize -Wno-deprecated-builtins -Wno-bitfield-constant-conversion -Wno-deprecated-this-capture -Wshadow -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -fno-ident -fno-strict-aliasing -fstack-protector-strong -fcolor-diagnostics -fmerge-all-constants -fcrash-diagnostics-dir=../../tools/clang/crashreports -mllvm -instcombine-lower-dbg-declare=0 -ffp-contract=off -fcomplete-member-pointers -arch arm64 -fno-global-isel -mno-outline -Wno-builtin-macro-redefined -D__DATE__= -D__TIME__= -D__TIMESTAMP__= -ffile-compilation-dir=. -no-canonical-prefixes -ftrivial-auto-var-init=pattern -O0 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g2 -gdwarf-aranges -Xclang -debug-info-kind=limited -isysroot ../../../../../../../../Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.3.sdk -mmacos-version-min=10.13 -fvisibility=hidden -Xclang -add-plugin -Xclang find-bad-constructs -Xclang -plugin-arg-find-bad-constructs -Xclang raw-ref-template-as-trivial-member -Xclang -plugin-arg-find-bad-constructs -Xclang check-stack-allocated -Wheader-hygiene -Wstring-conversion -Wtautological-overlap-compare -Wexit-time-destructors -Wglobal-constructors -Wno-shadow -Wctad-maybe-unsupported -Wimplicit-retain-self -Wstrict-overflow -Wmissing-field-initializers -Wimplicit-retain-self -Wobjc-missing-property-synthesis -Wno-undefined-bool-conversion -Wno-tautological-undefined-compare -std=c++20 -Wno-trigraphs -fobjc-call-cxx-cdtors -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -nostdinc++ -isystem../../buildtools/third_party/libc++/trunk/include -isystem../../buildtools/third_party/libc++abi/trunk/include -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fobjc-arc -c ../../third_party/webrtc/modules/desktop_capture/mac/screen_capturer_mac.mm -o obj/third_party/webrtc/modules/desktop_capture/desktop_capture_objc/screen_capturer_mac.o
../../third_party/webrtc/modules/desktop_capture/mac/screen_capturer_mac.mm:462:11: error: 'CGDisplayStreamUpdateGetRects' is only available on macOS 13.0 or newer [-Werror,-Wunguarded-availability-new]
          CGDisplayStreamUpdateGetRects(updateRef, kCGDisplayStreamUpdateDirtyRects, &count);
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../../../../../../../Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Headers/CGDisplayStream.h:106:37: note: 'CGDisplayStreamUpdateGetRects' has been marked as being introduced in macOS 13.0 here, but the deployment target is macOS 10.13.0
CG_EXTERN const CGRect * __nullable CGDisplayStreamUpdateGetRects(CGDisplayStreamUpdateRef __nullable updateRef,
                                    ^
../../third_party/webrtc/modules/desktop_capture/mac/screen_capturer_mac.mm:462:11: note: enclose 'CGDisplayStreamUpdateGetRects' in an @available check to silence this warning
          CGDisplayStreamUpdateGetRects(updateRef, kCGDisplayStreamUpdateDirtyRects, &count);
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../third_party/webrtc/modules/desktop_capture/mac/screen_capturer_mac.mm:472:45: error: 'kCGDisplayStreamShowCursor' is only available on macOS 13.0 or newer [-Werror,-Wunguarded-availability-new]
                           (const void* []){kCGDisplayStreamShowCursor},
                                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../../../../../../../Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Headers/CGDisplayStream.h:195:30: note: 'kCGDisplayStreamShowCursor' has been marked as being introduced in macOS 13.0 here, but the deployment target is macOS 10.13.0
CG_EXTERN const CFStringRef  kCGDisplayStreamShowCursor CG_AVAILABLE_BUT_DEPRECATED(13.0, 14.0, "Please use ScreenCaptureKit API's SCStreamConfiguration showsCursor property instead");  /* CFBoolean - defaults to false */
                             ^
../../third_party/webrtc/modules/desktop_capture/mac/screen_capturer_mac.mm:472:45: note: enclose 'kCGDisplayStreamShowCursor' in an @available check to silence this warning
                           (const void* []){kCGDisplayStreamShowCursor},
                                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../third_party/webrtc/modules/desktop_capture/mac/screen_capturer_mac.mm:478:41: error: 'CGDisplayStreamCreate' is only available on macOS 13.0 or newer [-Werror,-Wunguarded-availability-new]
    CGDisplayStreamRef display_stream = CGDisplayStreamCreate(
                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../../../../../../../Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Headers/CGDisplayStream.h:243:41: note: 'CGDisplayStreamCreate' has been marked as being introduced in macOS 13.0 here, but the deployment target is macOS 10.13.0
CG_EXTERN CGDisplayStreamRef __nullable CGDisplayStreamCreate(CGDirectDisplayID display,
                                        ^
../../third_party/webrtc/modules/desktop_capture/mac/screen_capturer_mac.mm:478:41: note: enclose 'CGDisplayStreamCreate' in an @available check to silence this warning
    CGDisplayStreamRef display_stream = CGDisplayStreamCreate(
                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../third_party/webrtc/modules/desktop_capture/mac/screen_capturer_mac.mm:482:23: error: 'CGDisplayStreamStart' is only available on macOS 13.0 or newer [-Werror,-Wunguarded-availability-new]
      CGError error = CGDisplayStreamStart(display_stream);
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../../../../../../../Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Headers/CGDisplayStream.h:273:19: note: 'CGDisplayStreamStart' has been marked as being introduced in macOS 13.0 here, but the deployment target is macOS 10.13.0
CG_EXTERN CGError CGDisplayStreamStart(CGDisplayStreamRef cg_nullable displayStream)
                  ^
../../third_party/webrtc/modules/desktop_capture/mac/screen_capturer_mac.mm:482:23: note: enclose 'CGDisplayStreamStart' in an @available check to silence this warning
      CGError error = CGDisplayStreamStart(display_stream);
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../third_party/webrtc/modules/desktop_capture/mac/screen_capturer_mac.mm:485:35: error: 'CGDisplayStreamGetRunLoopSource' is only available on macOS 13.0 or newer [-Werror,-Wunguarded-availability-new]
      CFRunLoopSourceRef source = CGDisplayStreamGetRunLoopSource(display_stream);
                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../../../../../../../Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Headers/CGDisplayStream.h:295:41: note: 'CGDisplayStreamGetRunLoopSource' has been marked as being introduced in macOS 13.0 here, but the deployment target is macOS 10.13.0
CG_EXTERN CFRunLoopSourceRef __nullable CGDisplayStreamGetRunLoopSource(CGDisplayStreamRef cg_nullable displayStream)
                                        ^
../../third_party/webrtc/modules/desktop_capture/mac/screen_capturer_mac.mm:485:35: note: enclose 'CGDisplayStreamGetRunLoopSource' in an @available check to silence this warning
      CFRunLoopSourceRef source = CGDisplayStreamGetRunLoopSource(display_stream);
                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../third_party/webrtc/modules/desktop_capture/mac/screen_capturer_mac.mm:498:33: error: 'CGDisplayStreamGetRunLoopSource' is only available on macOS 13.0 or newer [-Werror,-Wunguarded-availability-new]
    CFRunLoopSourceRef source = CGDisplayStreamGetRunLoopSource(stream);
                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../../../../../../../Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Headers/CGDisplayStream.h:295:41: note: 'CGDisplayStreamGetRunLoopSource' has been marked as being introduced in macOS 13.0 here, but the deployment target is macOS 10.13.0
CG_EXTERN CFRunLoopSourceRef __nullable CGDisplayStreamGetRunLoopSource(CGDisplayStreamRef cg_nullable displayStream)
                                        ^
../../third_party/webrtc/modules/desktop_capture/mac/screen_capturer_mac.mm:498:33: note: enclose 'CGDisplayStreamGetRunLoopSource' in an @available check to silence this warning
    CFRunLoopSourceRef source = CGDisplayStreamGetRunLoopSource(stream);
                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../third_party/webrtc/modules/desktop_capture/mac/screen_capturer_mac.mm:500:5: error: 'CGDisplayStreamStop' is only available on macOS 13.0 or newer [-Werror,-Wunguarded-availability-new]
    CGDisplayStreamStop(stream);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../../../../../../../Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Headers/CGDisplayStream.h:285:19: note: 'CGDisplayStreamStop' has been marked as being introduced in macOS 13.0 here, but the deployment target is macOS 10.13.0
CG_EXTERN CGError CGDisplayStreamStop(CGDisplayStreamRef cg_nullable displayStream)
                  ^
../../third_party/webrtc/modules/desktop_capture/mac/screen_capturer_mac.mm:500:5: note: enclose 'CGDisplayStreamStop' in an @available check to silence this warning
    CGDisplayStreamStop(stream);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
7 errors generated.
[20444/54517] CXX obj/third_party/webrtc/modules/pacing/pacing/packet_router.o
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

how to resolve this issue? I have read the docs https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/main/docs/mac_arm64.md and already add `target_cpu = "arm64"` in file `chromium/src/out/Default/args.gn`. the xcode version is `Version 14.3 (14E222b)`. this is the args.gn file content:

```
➜  Default git:(64ca7395b4) cat args.gn
# Set build arguments here. See `gn help buildargs`.
target_cpu = "arm64"
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same error attempting to compile Chromium on macOS 13.4.1 today. I ended up making a small modification to the default clang compiler arguments in `build/config/compiler/BUILD.gn`, which allowed the build to complete successfully.

```
diff --git a/build/config/compiler/BUILD.gn b/build/config/compiler/BUILD.gn
--- a/build/config/compiler/BUILD.gn
--- b/build/config/compiler/BUILD.gn
@@ -1644,6 +1644,8 @@ config("default_warnings") {
        # which we no longer use. Check if it makes sense to remove
        # this as well. http://crbug.com/316352
        "-Wno-unneeded-internal-declaration",
+
+       "-Wno-unguarded-availability-new",
      ]
 
      if (!is_nacl || is_nacl_saigo) {
```

Link to the line on Chromium's GitHub mirror: https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/4378d583b52c891b6429ae704bf5ecb252375997/build/config/compiler/BUILD.gn#L1742C6-L1742C6

Normally it's worth fixing the availability warnings, but for my use case I was building Chromium for myself and not planning distribute it to others on an earlier version of macOS.

Answer (score 1):

I see that the posted compiler command-line includes the argument `-mmacos-version-min=10.13`, which is to say, it wants to compile an executable that can run under MacOS 10.13 (aka "High Sierra") or newer.

Such a program may not legally call a function that is only available in MacOS 13.0 (aka "Ventura") or newer, hence the error message.

I suggest that you find the location in your build-config where `-mmacos-version-min=10.13` is specified, and change it to something like `-mmacos-version-min=13.0` instead; or if you really do need your program to be runnable under High Sierra, then you'll need to rewrite the code so that it doesn't call any functions that aren't supported by the 10.13/High Sierra version of the OS.  (Actually there is a way to make those function calls conditional, so that they only get called when the program is running on an OS that supports them, and some other codepath gets called otherwise; but I'm not very familiar with that technique so rather than try to describe it I'll just present a [link to Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/WeakLinking.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002378-106633) for it)

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods:
The first one is add gn arg

`treat_warnings_as_errors = true`;

And the second one is：

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push 
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wunguarded-availability-new"

// put your error code here

#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```